# Looping through list containing string

Tags: python

Hello I am a GCSE student and I am trying to populate an empty 2D array

Here is the code below:

```
#Array

Days = ["Mon1","Tue1","Wed1","Thu1","Fri1","Mon2","Tue2","Wed2","Thu2","Fri2","Mon3","Tue3","Wed3","Thu3","Fri3","Mon4","Tue4","Wed4","Thu4","Fri4"]
Buses = ["Bus A","Bus B","Bus C","Bus D","Bus E","Bus  F"]
BusData = [ [], [], [], [],  #Bus A
            [], [], [], [],  #Bus B
            [], [], [], [],  #Bus C
            [], [], [], [],  #Bus D
            [], [], [], [],  #Bus E
            [], [], [], [] ] #Bus F
```

So what I am trying to do is fill the bus data array with numbers. I started off doing somthing likes this:

```
for i in range(Buses): #Input
    ChosenDay = input("Enter day [Format: Day(week number)]")
    ChosenBus = input("Enter bus [Bus A - Bus B]")
    Data = input("input data")
    BusData[0].append(Data)
    print(BusData)
```

But I relised it wouldnt work like that as I got an error like this.

> for i in range(Buses): #Input TypeError: 'list' object cannot be
>
> interpreted as an integer

Is there a way to loop through a list that doesnt contain any numbers in it? And how do you populate a 2D list in GCSE format. Sorry if this is unclear I am still gcse student.

Comment: `range(len(Buses))`

Comment: You should try **for i in Buses:**

Comment: `Buses` is a list. How do you expect it to work on `range`? But I don't understand why you loop over that anyway.

Comment: I want it to loop as many times as days thou

Comment: Maybe you should get clear on what you want to know, delete the questions for now, edit it into shape and undelete later. "Evolving" questions get you downvotes because they are not answerable.

Comment: just do for i in Days if you are after looping the days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
for i in Buses
```

No need for the range bit. You could also do

```
for i in range(len(Buses))
```

but I don't see why you'd do that when you could just use the former.

Comment: @KarimMousa if it solved your problem you can click the green check mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A python `range` must receive an interval, like this: range(1, 10). Or just an integer: range(10), which implies 0 as the beginning of the interval. In your case, you are passing a list object to the function range, when you should pass an integer or an interval.

To correct your code, just put `for i in range(len(Buses))` instead of `for i in range(Buses)`.

So, the `for` will iterate from 0 to the length-1 of the Buses list.